# In auto boxing, is the conversion based on the variable/reference that we assign to or the other way around?

Tags: java, autoboxing

```
public class TestBox {
    Integer i;
    int j;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        TestBox t = new TestBox();
        t.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        j = i;
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I get a null pointer exception on line `j=i`.
Although if this line is transformed as `i=j` i get the out put as `0 0` which is the default values of int.
My question is, when `i` is assigned to `j` , shouldn't `i` get unboxed as an int variable and take the default value of 0 instead of its original default null ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [**JLS §5.1.8**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException

To avoid NPE, you need to initialize `i` (an `Integer`) before you try to assign it to a primitive

Answer (score 5):

Compiler translates this assignment

```
j = i;
```

... into this:

```
j = i.intValue( );
```

If `i` is null, you get NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no equivalent of `null` in primitives. When you try to unbox `i` which is `null` to primitive `j` , it will be a NullPointerException as `i` is `null`. Unboxing `null` always throws NullPointerException. This is as per the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

> If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `i`, then `i` is `null` and no unboxing could be done on it.

Answer (score 0):

initialize i with some values like

```
Integer i = someValue;
```

Your Integer i is not initialized. If you use eclipse that will show a error

Answer (score 0):

Zero is defined as the default value of a primitive integer instance variable,  and this is the only context where this default applies. It would be quite unsafe to assume zero out of thin air for a null-Integer value. Wisely, Java designers did not define it that way.